# Rails before_save method fails to execute 'else' block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Here is my before_save method:

```
  before_save :check_postal

  def check_postal
    first_three = self.postal_code[0..2]
    first_three.downcase!

    postal = Postal.find_by_postal_code(first_three)

    if postal
      self.zone_id = postal.zone_id
    else
      PostalError.create(postal_code: self.postal_code)
      return false
    end
  end
```

Everything runs fine when `self.zone_id = postal.zone_id` but inside the `else` statement, my `PostalError.create(postal_code: self.postal_code)` doesn't save the record to the database..

I know it's got something to do with the `return false` statement, because when I remove it, it saves fine -- but then that defeats the purpose..

How can I get a new `PostalError` record to save while returning false to prevent the current object from saving..

Comment: Hmm, an interesting problem. I'm looking in to this as well; my only suggestion at the moment is what would happen if you moved the `PostalError.create...` code in to an `:after_save` block instead. Make a temporary `attr_accessor :did_save_failed` or something like that, and then check that boolean in the `after_save` and create the  `PostalError` object if necessary.

Comment: The problem is if the save fails, i wont have a record anywhere to check it's `:did_save_failed attr`

I think i solved this by moving the PostalError.create over to the controller instead..

Comment: You certainly would be able to check the `did_save_fail` attribute in the `after_save`; the model still exists as a ruby object, even if it didn't get persisted to the database at any point. But the controller solutions work too. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

You're exactly right: the problem is the `before_save`.

The entirety of the save process is wrapped in a transaction. If the save fails, whether it be because of a validation failure, an exception being rolled back or something else, the transaction is rolled back. This undoes the creation of your PostalError record.

Normally this is a good thing - it's so that incomplete saves don't leave detritus around

I can think of two ways to solve this. One is to not create the record there at all: use a [after_rollback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_rollback) hook to execute it once the danger has passed.

The other way is to create that record using a different database connection (since transactions are a per connection thing). An easy way to do that is to use a different thread:

```
Thread.new { PostalError.create(...)}.join
```

I stuck the `join` on there so that this waits for the thread to complete rather than adding a degree of concurrency to your app that you might not expect.

Comment: +1 for the the link to `after_rollback`. I'd never heard of that. And then you drop another knowledge gem on `thread.join` to stop concurrency! Very cool!

Answer (score -2):

i don't know, but i trying to guess the solve.

```
else
  PostalError.create(postal_code: self.postal_code)
  self.zone_id = postal.zone_id
end
```